# JSON Decode - returning undefined index

Tags: php, json

Am trying to get more familiar with JSON decoding, so here's what I got:

```
$json = '{"id":[{"tier": "SILVER"}]}';
$array = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($array["id"]['tier']);
```

I am trying to fetch the 'tier', but it's resulting the following error: `Notice: Undefined index: tier`

I have tried certain things such as `var_dump($array['tier']);`, `var_dump($array[0]['tier']);` but nothing seems to work and I can not find a lot of information about this.

After the `Notice`it also returns `NULL`. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `id` key in the resulting array will contain an numerically indexed array of arrays.
To access, you need to specify the key in that array, in this case `0` as there is only a single element

```
var_dump($array["id"][0]['tier']);
```

If you where to decode to an object rather than forcing an associate array (by omitting the `true` in the `json_decode` call), you might find the syntax a little easier to read:

```
$json = '{"id":[{"tier": "SILVER"}]}';
$obj = json_decode($json);

var_dump($obj->id[0]->tier);
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! This perfectly answered my question. I will mark you as an answer when I can!

Comment: @ShadowBoost No problem, glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the first item `[0]`on the array `["id"]`
Try this:

```
$json = '{"id":[{"tier": "SILVER"}]}';
$array = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($array["id"][0]['tier']); 
//string(6) "SILVER"
```